# Python, rename a list with one of its values

Tags: python

I need to manipulate several list in python and I need each of them to take the name of the 3rd value it contains, but I can't get around the syntax for this.

Thanks

Edit:

I am writing a plugin for nagios that pulls data from a mssql server and I need to format the data for nagios perfdata.
I have already done most of the work, I just need to format the data.

```
def main():

parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)
parser.add_option("-H", "--host", dest="host", help="hostname or ip address to check", default="localhost")
parser.add_option("-u", "--user", help="DB username", type="string")
parser.add_option("-p", "--password", help="DB password")
parser.add_option("-P", "--port", help="database port", default="1433")
parser.add_option("-d", "--database", help="Database to query")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

con_string = "DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER={0};PORT={1};UID={2};PWD={3};DATABASE={4}" . format(options.host,options.port,options.user,options.password,options.database)
try:
    con = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
except:
    print "CRITICAL: error connecting, wrong options or database may be down"
    print sys.exc_info()
    exit(2) # crtical

# if we are connected, let's fetch some data!    
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

now, I need to print the data for nagios perfdata. I never needed the perfdata to have dynamic names, so I am stuck.

I usually do something like:

```
print 'ramTotal={0:.2f}{1}' .format(ramTotal/1024,UOM)
```

But I can't put the value of row[3] where I need it

```
print 'row[3]={0:.1f}{1}' .format(row[0],row[1])
```

does not work

Comment: Have you tried anything? We can help you with the syntax

Comment: Generally dynamically creating variables with specific names is the wrong answer, use a dictionary instead.

Comment: "..take the name of the 3rd value it contains.." uhh, *what*?

Comment: Post your code please we are not mind readers. although some might be, but they will still not help you until you post the code.

Comment: "I need each of them to take the name of the 3rd value it contains" - What is the name of a value? Values usually don't have "names" other than the variable name, but in this case it's a list, so it doesn't have a name, only an index. You you need to clarify here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
all_my_lists = {} #USE A DICT!!!
all_my_list[listx[2]] = listx  #listx[2] gives the 3rd value in listx
```

I think is what you are looking for ... if you really want to set variable names you will need to mess with locals() and globals() ... which is gross

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other commenters that dynamically naming a created variable is not usually a good approach.

But in the spirit of actually answering the question that was asked and trusting the author (and readers) to know when and whether it is appropriate, this is another method to achieve the same goal:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'foo']
l2 = ['c', 'd', 'bar']
l3 = ['e', 'f', 'baz']

lists_to_rename = [l1, l2, l3]

for some_list in lists_to_rename:
    exec("%s = some_list"%(some_list[2]))

print foo, bar, baz
```

*I repeat*: I'm not endorsing this as good; it's almost surely not the right way to solve your problem. I just like trying to answer the question as stated, for completeness and future reference ability.

Comment: If that is not enough advice, there's some more: "you THINK you want to do what this answer says, but actually you want to do what the answer suggesting a dictionary says".

Comment: +1 for showing how to do it ... even if it is typically a (very) bad idea (I suppose there are some potential use cases for this type of thing)

Comment: Some metaprogramming applications are well-solved with this kind of thing. One will usually encapsulate all of it into a decorator or something, and then the decorator can act almost like markup to inject functionality or create lots of side functionality with no extra programming.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, globals() is a dict with your variables. But it isn't good idea to update it by hands. You should create you own dict with keys are 3rd level variables and values are lists. Or you can create some simple class, because after you can update object from this class with attributes from your lists:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["d", "e", "j", "k"]]
map(lambda elem: setattr(a, elem[2], elem), list_of_lists)
a.__dict__     # Out[]: {'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'j': ['d', 'e', 'j', 'k']}
```

But this way you can't do some weird things! (You want some weird things, am I right?)
With dict you can!

```
a = {}
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 2, 3, 4], [lambda x:x, lambda x: x * x, lambda x: lambda y: x + y]]
for elem in list_of_lists:
    a[elem[2]] = elem

# {3: [1, 2, 3, 4],
#  <function __main__.<lambda>>: [<function __main__.<lambda>>,
# <function __main__.<lambda>>,
# <function __main__.<lambda>>],
# 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

Comment: The relevant `dict` might also be `locals()` if the location where the rename happens is not at global scope.

Comment: Yes of course. But I think it is bad idea to dinamycally changing built-in scope. My standpoint is making your own scope for change it dinamycally.

Comment: I'm just saying that `globals()` might *not* have the variables that need to be dynamically renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it like this:

```
for row in rows:
    print '{0}-{1}={2:.1f}'.format(row[3], row[2], row[1])
```